# Is it possible to make custom Chart.js labels that update chart data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a graph represent users songs with ratings bigger than 3 on a scale of 1-5 from each of the users listening sessions. Each line represents a user.
The graph:

[image]

the code:

```
            Object.values(researchData.userStatistics).forEach(user => {
                i++;
                if (user.sessions) {
                    usersLikedDataPl.push({
                        data: user.sessions.liked,
                        label: "User " + i,
                        borderColor: randomDarkRgbColor(),
                        fill: false
                    });
            }
            })                    

            let usersLikedGraphPl = {
                labels: Array.from({length: researchData.userStatistics.maxSessionLength}, (_, i) => "session: " + (i + 1)),
                datasets: usersLikedDataPl
            };


            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: usersLikedGraphPl,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'liked Graph'
                    }
                }
            });
```

each user has a data object, contain array's for liked(rate>3) unliked(rate<3) and indifferent(rate=3). Each array index represents a listening session. The user has also the same structure of ratings for each of his songs playlists. See example:

```
user: {
"sessions": {
    "liked": [0,6,3,2,1,1,0,0],
    "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
},
"playlists": {
    "lad": {
        "playlistName": "lad",
        "liked": [0,2,1,0,1,0,0,0],
        "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    "ARANA99DC": {
        "playlistName": "ARANA99DC",
        "liked": [0,4,2,2,0,1,0,0],
        "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    "FRA60DC": {
        "playlistName": "FRA60DC",
        "liked": [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    "FRA50DC": {
        "playlistName": "FRA50DC",
        "liked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    "FRA40DC": {
        "playlistName": "FRA40DC",
        "liked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    "FRA30DC": {
        "playlistName": "FRA30DC",
        "liked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "indifferent": [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        "unliked": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ]
    }
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do:
The lines of the graph will still represent users and songs score, but the labels will be the playlist(ARANA99DC, FRA30DC, FRA30DC...)
When the user presses the playlist label, for each of the users that have the playlist, the user.sessions.liked array will be updated to be: user.sessions.liked-user.playlists.PLAYLISTNAME.liked. In other words - hide the song count from the toggled playlists from all of the users that use it.

Using the example above: If the user press the lable ARANA99DC, the user line will be update to: [0, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0] - [0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0] = [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Pressing ARANA99DC again and the user's line will be updated back to [0, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]

Is it possible doing it with Chart.js?

Comment: A suggestion to your question. If you can provide your data in codes, don't post pictures.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've replaced the picture with the object code.